# Why is Android Studio 4.2 sometimes failing to build?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have seen a repeated problem on my project when I upgraded from AS 4.1.2 to 4.2.1. I will make a simple change, and when I try to run (which invokes a build request) I see the error I have documented in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67438562/android-studio-4-2-throws-a-null-pointer-exception-on-incremental-builds).

I have also seen a problem whereby when I ask for a full rebuild (Build -> Rebuild Project) I get an error that AS cannot delete the 'build' directory. In fact, checking for the build directory in my file system shows that it is, in fact, gone. When I immediately request a rebuild a second time, it succeeds.

I have documented this in a bug report [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187859154).

I cannot imagine what setting might be in my project that could cause either of these errors, but hoping someone here might have an idea.

If I create a brand new sample project in the same top level directory (all my projects are in directories off of C:\BLD\AndroidStudioProjects), neither of the errors mentioned above occurs.

Comment: For me is the same, but I haven't the nullpointer. I have to do all the time invalidate cache and restart, and it is very awful.